# Size of single listview item android

Tags: android, android-listview

Does anyone know the standard size of a single listview item in android, in dpi or pixels?

Or maybe there isn't a standard?

Answer (score 10):

Android defines a "preferred size" using,

```
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
```

Documented [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#listPreferredItemHeight) as well.

Answer (score 4):

there is a strongly recommended list view item size, which you should use: [48dip](http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html#48dp-rhythm). This is recommended by the new Android Design Guidelines.